# How can I extract warnings/messages from the system console in blender to python script

Tags: python, scripting

How can I extract warnings or other messages from the Blenders system console into my Python script? For instance, I would like to be able to check if a specific warning has occurred during the use of an operator.

One example of this is when you solve your camera motion and receive the message, "Warning: Some data failed to reconstruct (see console for details)," in the system console. I want to be able to check in Python if this message has occurred.

Comment: Thats now how python works, unless the errors are from your script, but from description  seems like some addon fails. You would have to inject your code to plugin or code your self some wrappers, unless you simply mean exception, then use `try` and  `except <yourtype>`

Comment: I am trying to detect if the message "Warning: Some data failed to reconstruct (see console for details)" appear in the system console when I use the solve camera motion operator.

Comment: This is the way, but It won't work easily and I can't tell you how to do it cause I don't know if it will work with blender https://stackoverflow.com/a/22822313/11650254, 
Why do you  even need that warning in first place?

Comment: @GrzegorzKrug: it doesn't - at least when i tried it. Maybe i made it wrong.

Comment: I have also tried that method but I don't find it woking.